# Timeout after n-seconds if a certain value is not emitted

Tags: rxjs, angular6, observable, angularfire2

I am using angularfire2 to push in Firebase on object with a status NEW. My backend is listening to writes on that list and will take actions on each new request with status NEW.
I want to handle 3 possible outcomes: SUCCESS, ERROR and timeout.

```
add(book: Book) {
        return this.authentication.user.pipe(
            take(1),
            switchMap(user => {
                // Set owner for the backend to handle correctly
                book.setOwner(user.uid);

                // Add book request
                const queueRef = this._afqueue.list(this.ADD_BOOK_QUEUE_PATH);
                const pushPromise = queueRef.push({ status: { code: 'NEW' }, ...book })
                    .then(ref => {
                        console.log('Request to add a new book added to queue.');
                        return ref;
                    }) as Promise<any>;
                return from(pushPromise);
            }),
            switchMap(ref => {
                return this._afqueue.object(this.ADD_BOOK_QUEUE_PATH + '/' + ref.key)
                    .valueChanges();
            }),
            map(snap => snap['status']),
            filter(status => status['code'] === 'SUCCESS' || status['code'] === 'ERROR'),
            switchMap(status => {
                if (status['code'] === 'SUCCESS') {
                    return Observable.create(function(observer) {
                        observer.complete(status['book_id']);
                      });
                    //return status['book_id'];
                }
                else if (status['code'] === 'ERROR') {
                    throw(status['error']);
                }
            }),
            timeout(60000), // timeout after 60 secondes
        );
    }
```

Timeout occurs whether I receive an ERROR or a SUCCESS. How could I timeout only if I receive none after 60 secondes ?

Comment: Move `timeout` upper, before which `switchMap` you want to `timeout`

Comment: You can use `catchError` to turn `error` notifications into `next` notifications but then you won't receive any erros if the remote call fails

Comment: Also, just a hint: use `of` instead `Observable.create` and `throwError` instead of `throw` (it seems like you're using JS throw operator, instead of RxJS).

Comment: Using of seems to work. However, replacing `throw` by `throwError` generates the following error `Uncaught TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected`. Finally, moving the timeout upper (right before the last switchMap) still generates a timeout (even if a SUCCESS is returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote it this way, which is working:

```
add(book: Book) {
        return this.authentication.user.pipe(
            take(1),
            mergeMap(user => {
                // Set owner for the backend to handle correctly
                book.setOwner(user.uid);

                // Add book request
                const queueRef = this._afqueue.list(this.ADD_BOOK_QUEUE_PATH);
                const pushPromise = queueRef.push({ status: { code: 'NEW' }, ...book })
                    .then(ref => {
                        console.log('Request to add a new book added to queue.');
                        return ref;
                    }) as Promise<any>;
                return from(pushPromise);
            }),
            mergeMap(ref => {
                return this._afqueue.object(this.ADD_BOOK_QUEUE_PATH + '/' + ref.key)
                    .valueChanges();
            }),
            map(snap => snap['status']),
            filter(status => (status['code'] === 'SUCCESS' || status['code'] === 'ERROR')),
            first(),
            timeout(60000), // timeout after 60 secondes
            mergeMap(status => {
                console.log(status);
                console.log(status['code'])
                if (status['code'] === 'SUCCESS') {
                    return of(status['book_id']);
                    //return status['book_id'];
                }
                else if (status['code'] === 'ERROR') {
                    throwError(status['error']);
                }
            })
        );
    }
```